# Why does OSX always print ApplePersistence=YES to stderr?

Tags: applescript, console

Whenever my mac boots up, each task that is launched prints the following message. See for example

`22/09/16 14:13:45.070 TMHelperAgent[6171]: ApplePersistence=YES`

Whenever I run an AppleScript, I get the same message printed to stderr as well.

`osascript -e 'tell application id "com.spotify.client" to quit'
2016-09-23 08:39:15.084 osascript[1257:28252] ApplePersistence=YES`

Is this normal behavior? How can I stop the OS from printing this message every time?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is printed to STDERR. You can simply redirect the output to /dev/null:

```
osascript -e 'tell application id "com.spotify.client" to quit' 2>/dev/null
```